# validating SOAP response in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, soap

I am working on a module that connects to a third party API using SOAP. What I want to know is

- what are the best practices when developing with SOAP?
- How to validate the SOAP response? 
  ex - if the SOAP response comes in XML format, how to check if a specific node is available
- any helper Methods to use

Thanks